# my sql sub_query return_more than one row

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my mysql_query  i want to  add this query into my main query  but the problem is  when im add it to query it show sub query returns more than one row

```
(
    SELECT date(trn_orderheader_approvedby.dtApprovedDate) AS CREATE_DATE
    FROM trn_orderheader_approvedby
    WHERE trn_orderheader_approvedby.intApproveLevelNo IN('-10')
) 
AS Order_COMPLETED_DATE

 SELECT
TB1.*, (
    SELECT
        SUM(TRNS.dblQty *- 1)
    FROM
        ware_stocktransactions_bulk AS TRNS
    WHERE
        TRNS.intOrderNo = TB1.`NO`
    AND TRNS.intOrderYear = TB1.`YEAR`
    AND TRNS.intSalesOrderId = TB1.intSalesOrderId
    AND TRNS.intItemId = TB1.ITEM_ID
    AND TRNS.intLocationId = TB1.LOCATION_ID
    AND TRNS.strType IN ('ISSUE', 'RETSTORES')
) AS QTY,
(
    SELECT
        SUM(
            TRNS.dblQty * TRNS.dblGRNRate * mst_financeexchangerate.dblBuying *- 1
        )
    FROM
        ware_stocktransactions_bulk AS TRNS
    LEFT JOIN mst_financeexchangerate ON mst_financeexchangerate.dtmDate = TRNS.dtGRNDate
    AND mst_financeexchangerate.intCompanyId = TRNS.intCompanyId
    AND mst_financeexchangerate.intCurrencyId = TRNS.intCurrencyId
    WHERE
        TRNS.intOrderNo = TB1.`NO`
    AND TRNS.intOrderYear = TB1.`YEAR`
    AND TRNS.intSalesOrderId = TB1.intSalesOrderId
    AND TRNS.intItemId = TB1.ITEM_ID
    AND TRNS.intLocationId = TB1.LOCATION_ID
    AND TRNS.strType IN ('ISSUE', 'RETSTORES')
) AS AMOUNT,
(
    SELECT
        SUM(
            costing_sample_header.INK_COST
        )
    FROM
        costing_sample_header
    WHERE
        TB1.intSampleNo = costing_sample_header.SAMPLE_NO
    AND TB1.intSampleYear = costing_sample_header.SAMPLE_YEAR
    AND TB1.intRevisionNo = costing_sample_header.REVISION
    AND TB1.strCombo = costing_sample_header.COMBO
    AND TB1.strPrintName = costing_sample_header.PRINT
) AS INK_COST,
(
    SELECT
        SUM(
            costing_sample_header.SPECIAL_RM_COST
        )
    FROM
        costing_sample_header
    WHERE
        TB1.intSampleNo = costing_sample_header.SAMPLE_NO
    AND TB1.intSampleYear = costing_sample_header.SAMPLE_YEAR
    AND TB1.intRevisionNo = costing_sample_header.REVISION
    AND TB1.strCombo = costing_sample_header.COMBO
    AND TB1.strPrintName = costing_sample_header.PRINT
) AS RM_COST
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        tempory_rm_moved_orders_summery2.`NO`,
        tempory_rm_moved_orders_summery2.`YEAR`,
        trn_orderdetails.intSalesOrderId,
        trn_orderdetails.strSalesOrderNo,
        trn_orderdetails.strGraphicNo,
        trn_orderdetails.intSampleNo,
        trn_orderdetails.intSampleYear,
        trn_orderdetails.intRevisionNo,
        trn_orderdetails.strCombo,
        trn_orderdetails.strPrintName,
        mst_part.strName AS part,
        mst_locations.intId AS LOCATION_ID,
        mst_locations.strName AS LOCATION,
        trn_orderdetails.intQty,
        mst_maincategory.strName AS MAIN_CATEGORY,
        mst_subcategory.strName AS SUB_CATEGORY,
        mst_item.intId AS ITEM_ID,
        mst_item.strCode AS ITEM_CODE,
        mst_item.strName AS ITEM_NAME,
        mst_units.strCode AS UOM,
        trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.PRODUCTION_QTY,
        /* trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.CONS_PC,  
        trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.PRODUCTION_QTY, 
        trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.REQUIRED, sum( ifnull( 
            ware_stocktransactions_bulk.dblQty *- 1, 0 ) ) AS qty,*/
        /*sum( ifnull( ware_stocktransactions_bulk.dblQty * ware_stocktransactions_bulk.dblGRNRate * mst_financeexchangerate.dblBuying *- 1, 0 ) ) AS amount, */
        trn_orderdetails.dblPrice,
        mst_customer.strName AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
        mst_brand.strName AS BRAND_NAME,
        trn_orderheader.intStatus,

    IF (
        trn_orderheader.intStatus = 1,
        'Approved',

    IF (
        trn_orderheader.intStatus = 0,
        'Rejected',

    IF (
        trn_orderheader.intStatus =- 10,
        'Completed',

    IF (
        trn_orderheader.intStatus =- 2,
        'Cancel',

    IF (
        trn_orderheader.intStatus =- 1,
        'Revised',
        'Pending'
    )
    )
    )
    )
    ) AS STATUS,
            trn_orderdetails.dtDeliveryDate,
    mst_technique_groups.TECHNIQUE_GROUP_NAME
FROM
    ware_stocktransactions_bulk
INNER JOIN tempory_rm_moved_orders_summery2 ON ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderNo = tempory_rm_moved_orders_summery2.`NO`
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderYear = tempory_rm_moved_orders_summery2.`YEAR`
AND date(
    ware_stocktransactions_bulk.dtDate
) >= '2017-06-01'
INNER JOIN trn_orderdetails ON ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderNo = trn_orderdetails.intOrderNo
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderYear = trn_orderdetails.intOrderYear
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intSalesOrderId = trn_orderdetails.intSalesOrderId
INNER JOIN mst_part ON trn_orderdetails.intPart = mst_part.intId
INNER JOIN trn_orderheader ON trn_orderdetails.intOrderNo = trn_orderheader.intOrderNo
AND trn_orderdetails.intOrderYear = trn_orderheader.intOrderYear
INNER JOIN mst_item ON ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intItemId = mst_item.intId
INNER JOIN mst_maincategory ON mst_item.intMainCategory = mst_maincategory.intId
INNER JOIN mst_subcategory ON mst_item.intSubCategory = mst_subcategory.intId
INNER JOIN mst_units ON mst_item.intUOM = mst_units.intId
INNER JOIN mst_locations ON ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intLocationId = mst_locations.intId
INNER JOIN mst_customer ON trn_orderheader.intCustomer = mst_customer.intId
INNER JOIN trn_sampleinfomations ON trn_orderdetails.intSampleNo = trn_sampleinfomations.intSampleNo
AND trn_orderdetails.intSampleYear = trn_sampleinfomations.intSampleYear
AND trn_orderdetails.intRevisionNo = trn_sampleinfomations.intRevisionNo
INNER JOIN mst_brand ON trn_sampleinfomations.intBrand = mst_brand.intId
INNER JOIN mst_technique_groups ON trn_orderdetails.TECHNIQUE_GROUP_ID = mst_technique_groups.TECHNIQUE_GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN trn_po_prn_details_sales_order ON ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderYear = trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.ORDER_NO
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderYear = trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.ORDER_YEAR
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intSalesOrderId = trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.SALES_ORDER
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intItemId = trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.ITEM
WHERE
    ware_stocktransactions_bulk.strType IN ('ISSUE', 'RETSTORES')
AND ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderNo > 0
AND trn_po_prn_details_sales_order.ITEM IS NULL

/* GROUP BY ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intLocationId, ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderNo, ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intOrderYear, ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intSalesOrderId, ware_stocktransactions_bulk.intItemId */
) AS TB1here
```

Comment: Your sub query doesn't have anything to limit it to one particular order, so it will retrieve all records.

Comment: i want to get all date in WHERE trn_orderheader_approvedby.intApproveLevelNo IN('-10')

Comment: 'All dates' which means that 'when im add it to query it show sub query returns more than one row' which is exactly the problem you have.  The query needs to return the date for the particular order your working with- I would have thought.

Comment: yes i want to get all dates acording to my main_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution like this

```
       (
        SELECT
            trn_orderheader_approvedby.dtApprovedDate
        FROM
            trn_orderheader_approvedby
        WHERE
            trn_orderheader_approvedby.intApproveLevelNo = "-10" 
            AND trn_orderdetails.intOrderNo = trn_orderheader_approvedby.intOrderNo
            AND trn_orderdetails.intOrderYear = trn_orderheader_approvedby.intYear
        ORDER BY
            trn_orderheader_approvedby.dtApprovedDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS COMPLETED_DATE
```